# Parsing large XML using iterparse() consumes too much memory. Any alternative?

Tags: python, xml, memory, lxml

I am using python 2.7 with latest lxml library. I am parsing a large XML file with very homogenous structure and millions of elements. I thought lxml's `iterparse` would not build an internal tree while it parses, but apparently it does since memory usage grows until it crashes (around 1GB). Is there a way to parse large XML file using lxml without using a lot of memory?

I saw the [target parser interface](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#the-target-parser-interface) as one possibility, but I'm not sure if that will work any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Liza Daly's [fast_iter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/):

```
def fast_iter(context, func, args=[], kwargs={}):
    # http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    # Author: Liza Daly
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context
```

`fast_iter` removes elements from the tree after they have been parsed, and also previous elements (maybe with other tags) that are no longer needed.

It could be used like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
def process_element(elem):
    ...
context=ET.iterparse(filename, events=('end',), tag=...)        
fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

Comment: Nice article at the link.  +1

Comment: There's one gotcha with Liza's code; it expects unique tag names. If you have the same tag nested, then the internal one will be empty. (http://www.willmer.com/kb/2012/02/minor-gotcha-with-liza-dalys-fast_iter/ has a slightly longer answer, can't work out how to do a code example in this comment)

Comment: Rachel, I think the "gotcha" occurs if you use `events = ('start',)` in the call
to `ET.iterparse` and pass that `context` to `fast_iter`. In this case, elements
are deleted when the starting tag is reached rather than after the ending tag is
reached. This can lead to errors (logical or syntactical). [This
code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/829989/) demonstrates the problem. If this is the
error you are seeing, the fix is to change `start` to `end`.

Comment: Liza's approach doesn't help if the element you're looking for occurs far into the xml stream, at which point the parser has already consumed memory building the tree. This approach works better in that circumstance: http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it with a hint from http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing:

```
elems = ET.Element('MyElements')
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename):
    if is_needed(elem): # implement this condition however you like
        elems.append(elem)
    else:
        elem.clear()
```

This gives you a tree with only the elements you need, without requiring unnecessary memory during parsing.